# What step am I missing when reducing this boolean function/logic?

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

I'm trying to reduce a Boolean logic expression.  I'm putting the following expression in the Wolfram tool, and visually I understand the answer.  I'm missing a step in the reduction, however.  What am I missing?

My expression:

```
C(G~HX+HX+X)
```

The "answer":

```
CX
```

And here's what I reduce it to:

```
CX(G~H+H)
CX(G+H)
CXG+CXH
```

What's the step I'm missing that cancels/converts "G+H" to 1 to give me the correct answer?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format both, your questions and your answers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You factored X (correct operation) but forgot 1:
$$
C(G \overline{H} X+HX+X) = C(G \overline{H} +H+1)X = CX.$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
C(G \overline{H} X+HX+X) & = CG \overline{H} X+CHX+CX\\
 & = (CX)G \overline{H}+(CX)H+(CX)\\ 
 & = CX
\end{align}$$